# Form with unbound text field writing to a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I keep getting an error on `Dim R As Recordset` when I run this code on click:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    Dim R As Recordset

    Set R = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [tblLogData]")
    R.AddNew
    R![Data] = "Log entry" & Me.tDate.Value
    R.Update
    R.Close
    Set R = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be a little helpful to know what the error says.

Comment: I get Compile Error: User-Defined Type not Defined and it highlights Dim R As Recordset

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't remove the error:

```
Dim R As DAO.Recordset
```

you are missing a reference to the *Microsoft Office xx.0 Access database engine Object Library*.

Comment: I get Compile Error: User-Defined Type not Defined and it highlights Dim R As DAO.Recordset

Comment: Did you add the suggested Reference under Tools \ References in the VBA IDE?

Comment: I have OLE Automation, MS Access 14.0 Object Libary, and Visual Basic for Application.